# Java: String Formatting

Tags: java, string, class

Attempting to print out...

```
64506 St. Joseph, MO (+39.76580, +94.85060)
```

Current Code

```
public class PostalCodes {
private String city;
private double latitude;
private double longitude;
private double zip;
private String state;

public PostalCodes(double aZip, String aCity, String aState, double aLatitude, double aLongitude)
{
    city = aCity;
    latitude = aLatitude;
    longitude = aLongitude;
    zip = aZip;
    state = aState;
}

void setZip(double aZip)
{
    zip=aZip;
}

void setState(String aState)
{
    state=aState;
}


void setLocation(String aCity)
{
    city = aCity.trim();
}
void setLatitude(double lat)
{
    latitude = lat;
}
void setLongitude(double long1)
{
    longitude = long1;
}
public String getState()
{
    return state;
}
public double getZip()
{
    return zip;
}
public String getLocation()
{
    return city;
}
public double getLatitude()
{
    return latitude;
}
public double getLongitude()
{
return longitude;
}
public String toString()
{
    String result = String.format("%d %s,%s (%1.3f; %1.3f)",zip, city, state, latitude,longitude);
    return result;
}
```

}

I'm getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source)
at PostalCodes.toString(PostalCodes.java:63)
```

As an error. I did it exactly how I had down in my notes from class, not sure where I'm going wrong here. Thanks for your time and dumb it down for me if you could, first time Java programmer over here.

Comment: `%d` is for integer values! And your 'zip' is a `double`... (why? That is strange for a ZIP code)

Comment: To follow what fge said, I would avoid using numerical fields (integer, float, double) to store things like zip codes. Like phone numbers, they are less "numbers" and more a collection of characters that happen to be numbers (and are restricted to numbers). Additionally, for the sake of argument, should a zip code ever require a leading zero, you'd lose that with numerical fields. Also, text storage allows you to also store mixed character codes like Canadian postal codes and such (hypothetically speaking).

Answer (score 1):

*Since my comment is more or less an answer, I'm posting it here so I can elaborate*

As the others have said, your issue is to due to the incorrect formatter token. In short, `%d` is for integers, and `%f` is for floating-point numbers (which includes doubles).

However, I would avoid using numerical fields (integer, float, double) to store things like zip codes. Like phone numbers, they are less "numbers" and more a collection of characters that happen to be numbers (and also happen to be restricted to numbers in the case of US zip codes, for example).

Additionally, for the sake of argument, should a zip code ever require a leading zero, you wouldn't be able to preserve that with numerical fields. In other words, storing your zip code as a number would make `01234` come out as `1234`, which is not quite the same when it comes to identification values such as these.

Also, using non-numeric storage (ie text) allows you to store mixed character codes like Canadian postal codes (for example "K1Q 9S8") and such (hypothetically speaking). I assume this requirement is not relevant for your situation, but this kind of "future-proofing" is sometimes a good habit to adopt, especially given the other points I've described.

So, in practical terms, I would change the datatype of your `zip` variable to a `String`:

```
private String zip;
```

And use the string formatter token (`%s`) instead:

```
public String toString() {
    String result = String.format("%s %s,%s (%1.3f; %1.3f)",zip, city, state, latitude,longitude);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

%d is for integer values. Use %f for floats and doubles.

Answer (score 0):

zipcode should be int.  You declared a double for zip.